# Implicit declaration of function 'ccDrawColor4B' in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm really new to game programmming and i'm trying to pull over somebody elses example game to mine to just understand it a bit at a time but i'm stuck. When trying to pull the game over i'm getting the error :

```
 Implicit declaration of function 'ccDrawColor4B'
```

I've done a bit of a look around for the method and I can't find it so i've looked at the project which i'm copying from for clues and found that there's loads more files.  Below is the one i'm copying from..

[image]

And here is mine..

[image]

Am I missing a framework or something? When I type ccDr... it doesn't autofill either. Thanks for any help, sorry if this is totally a noobie question

Comment: ccDrawColor4B is defined in version 2.x but not 3.x of cocos2d. Your two projects are probably at 2 different releases. Figure out which one you want to use (recommend 3.x), and make certain that anything you copy in the target project uses the same version.

Comment: Is it worth me just finding the replacement method for these particular few drawing ones because the tutorial i'm using really seems great so far?

Comment: If this gets you into trouble, you should really be using the exact same version of cocos2d as was used in the tutorial. You'll still learn how to use it, and with greater ease.

Comment: I'm really struggling to find a tutorial on the current platform. Is there somewhere I can download a blank project with everything already in for cocos2d version 2.0?  Thanks for the responses, really helpful :)

Comment: Sure you can. Go to the old repo [cocos2d 2.x](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-classic) and read the section **How to start a new game**. In the repo you'll find all the releases (any version you need). And if you are new to git, just google how to download old releases from github.